# Postfix, MediaWiki, LAMP, Server won't send out emails

Tags: php, apache2, mediawiki, lamp

I'm not sure if the issue with with Postfix, MediaWiki, LAMP or what. Basically I configured an extension for MediaWiki for AccountRequest and it's supposed to send an email out to the user that created to give them login information. Emails aren't sent out. I figured it might be something to do with settings in localsettings.php but when I add the $wgSMTP array listed below but with my info I start getting [3b2f8024] 2015-11-24 20:19:31: Fatal exception of type "MWException" showing up on mediawiki.

```
$wgSMTP = array(
'host'     => "mail.example.com", // could also be an IP address. Where the SMTP server is located
'IDHost'   => "example.com",      // Generally this will be the domain name of your website (aka mywiki.org)
'port'     => 25,                 // Port to use when connecting to the SMTP server
'auth'     => true,               // Should we use SMTP authentication (true or false)
'username' => "my_user_name",     // Username to use for SMTP authentication (if being used)
'password' => "my_password"       // Password to use for SMTP authentication (if being used)
);
```

If I leave the localsettings.php settings as enabled and all that it will act like it works but users never get the email.

```
$wgEnableEmail = true;
$wgEnableUserEmail = true; # UPO


$wgEmergencyContact = "apache@10.00.000.000";
$wgPasswordSender = "apache@10.00.000.000";

$wgEnotifUserTalk = true; # UPO
$wgEnotifWatchlist = false; # UPO
$wgEmailAuthentication = true;
```

Wondering of a good workaround for this or if someone can point me in the right direction to get this fixed that would be awesome. I've spent hours googling without any results. If my question isn't clear or you need more information please just ask.

Comment: Did you check the mail logs?

Comment: No I haven't, so I should look at the logs for postfix and see what it's doing.

Comment: Sorry, I've been extremely busy the past few day. Here is what I'm getting from the logs, this is to any email sent, from test emails from cli and emails mediawiki tries to send out. B6D5ACA24BF: to=<user@example.com>, relay=none, delay=225603, delays=225603/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.3.5, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=smtp.localdomain type=AAAA: Host not found) –

Also if I change main.cf to only use ipv4 is just changes dns type to A and still doesn't work.

Comment: if I run host example@gmail.com 8.8.8.8 in CLI I get a connection timed out messaged too.

Comment: I believe it's due to a proxy at work, contacting the correct team to get that taken care of.

Comment: If it is not a proxy trouble, check your server DNS client configuration

Answer (score 0):

Check that the [SMTP server is actually reachable](https://serverfault.com/a/207759/203035). With your $wgSMTP settings, do:

```
telnet mail.example.com 25
```

and see if you can connect. If not, either there is no SMTP server running there or there is a firewall. Double check the SMTP host and port, check instructions on how to open firewall in your distribution.